# Solving a given equation using a trigonometric identity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$2\sin2\theta -3\sin\theta =0$

Steps I took:

$$2(2\sin\theta \cos\theta )-3\sin\theta $$

$$4\sin\theta 2\cos\theta -3\sin$$

$$\sin\theta (8\cos\theta -3)=0$$

$\sin\theta =0$ so, $\theta =0+\pi k$

$8\cos\theta -3=0,\quad \cos\theta =\frac { 3 }{ 8 } $

The last part is giving me trouble and I feel that it has something to do with my algebra in the first few steps. Can someone giving me a hint in the right direction?

Comment: Seems like it's not 8 but 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your answer $$2(2\sin\theta \cos\theta )-3\sin\theta =0$$

$$4\sin\theta \cos\theta -3\sin\theta=0 \text{ (no more 2 here)}$$

$$\sin\theta (4\cos\theta -3)=0$$

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I treated $2sin\theta cos\theta $ as two separate terms meanwhile it was one combined term. Right?

Comment: Yes Thats correct

Comment: I happen to miss that quite often. Thank you.

Comment: we all do at times just more practice and you will remember